# How to start up the Kinova (JACO Arms) API in ROS?

Tags: ros, kinova

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I am working on already has a couple of "sample programs" to help move the arms. But looking upon the code for these programs, there seems to be an API involved. I am trying to understand the code, but it all relates to the API which I can't find and run. I understand this information is not enough, but does anyone have any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64850/how-to-start-up-the-kinova-(jaco-arms)-api-in-ros?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a new driver for the Jaco released recently. Announcement: http://www.ros.org/news/2013/07/ros-node-for-jaco.html  Documentation: http://www.ros.org/wiki/jaco

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have this ROS package? https://github.com/vecnatechnologies/JacoROS/blob/master/kinova_jaco/jaco_api/manifest.xml

---

Originally posted by [jnj11](https://answers.ros.org/users/5165/jnj11/) with karma: 61 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-06-18**:
@jnj11 - That's what confuses me. The sample programs shouldn't run if there was no API, right? So the package should be there. But I couldn't locate the files that are available on the link you sent me. I skipped them by mistake probably. Will check again I guess. Thank you though!